# How To add Models with OneToOneField to every of some ForeignKey Custom User Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

The following scenario:

I need a Custom User Model with ForeignKey to the user model.

> e.g.: a User can have some Planets

```
class UserPlanet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(default='planet', max_length=40)
```

For each created planet, there are other models that have a OneToOneField.

> e.g. a Model which contains size, color or its favorite animal, however:

```
class PlanetValues(models.Model):
    user_planet = models.OneToOneField(UserPlanet, related_name='planet_values', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=1000)
```

---

What is the best way for a Django View to choose one of the Planet and the Informations on a template was filtered to the corresponding planet.
This is a simple example, but the principle does not change. How can I handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you mean, as a very simple example, a view to select a `UserPlanet` based on a supplied `username` and `name` could look something like:

```py
def show_planet(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.GET['username'])
    planet = UserPlanet.objects.get(user=user, name=request.GET['name'])

    return render(request, 'show_planet.html'. {'planet', planet})
```

And then to render the values in the `show_planet.html` template:

```
<strong>Planet name:</strong><span>{{ planet.name }}</span>
<strong>Planet size:</strong><span>{{ planet.planet_values.size }}</span>
```

The above example assumes there will only be one `UserPlanet` for a given user and name. If that is not the case, you would have to `filter` the `UserPlanet` objects and then loop through the results in the template.